# How to set one radio button should be always active

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button, css-animations

I have a radio button with male and female.

I need a help in below issue.

1. I have to show the male radio button should be always active.
2. How do I increase the size? I tried to give some padding but getting the issue in the background.
3. How can I set some animation on it?

Would you help me in this?

```js
$('label.option').click(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').attr('checked',null);
  $('label.option').removeClass("checked");
  $(this).prev().attr('checked',"checked");
  $(this).addClass("checked");
})
```

```css
.border {
  border:1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.width-half {
  width: 75px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.checked {
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">
  <div class="width-half">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
    <label class="option">Male</label>
  </div>
  <div class="width-half">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
    <label class="option">Female</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Always active

Simply set your input attribute to checked

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>
```

And then target the label that is adjacent sibling to that input with checked state, like this

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

### 2. Size

Label is inline level element, simply set it to block, and then set the padding as you wish

```
label {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

### 3. Animate

Depends what would you like to animate, but simply setting the transition to all should do the trick.

```
label {
    transition: all 300ms ;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me and you also solved my 3 issues.Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

attribute `checked` can be used and an extra selector added for the styling of `label` to take effect:

- add attribute [`checked`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/radio) to `radio` *male*

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>
```

- then update CSS selector adding to the class selector `:checked +label`

```css
.checked, :checked +label{
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```js
$('label.option').click(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').attr('checked',null);
    $('label.option').removeClass("checked");
    $(this).prev().attr('checked',"checked");
    $(this).addClass("checked");
})
```

```css
.border{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}
.width-half{
    width: 75px;
}
input[type=radio]
{
    display: none;
}
.checked, :checked +label{
    background-color: #00a2ff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">
    <div class="width-half">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>
        <label class="option">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="width-half">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
        <label class="option">Female</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Notice that ...**

Javascript might not even be required since the HTML structure is compatible with CSS selector **if** `label` is properly linked to its `input` via the attribute `for`.

**ressource**

- https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

> **for**
>
> The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.width-half {
  width: 75px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

:checked+label {
  background-color: #00a2ff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="width-half">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" checked>
    <label class="option" for="male">Male</label>
  </div>
  <div class="width-half">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female">
    <label class="option" for="female">Female</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is also working for me. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

With php, you can achieve this by adding;

```
<?php $gender = $_POST["gender"]; ?>
<input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>
value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>
value="male">Male
```

and to add a css color or any thing you want to include so that a user will know its active you can create a class or id, name it anything you want and echo it, that is you will have something like this;

```
<?php $gender = $_POST["gender"]; ?>
<input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked" echo "id='highlight';?>
value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked" echo "id='highlight';?>
value="male">Male
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use radio button checked property to checked it by default,

```
<input type="radio" name="" value="male" checked="checked" />
```